# No sound from Bluetooth headset

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04.  My headset (MPOW H10) is connected and paired, as verified by **bluetoothmgr**. System Settings/Multimedia/Audio and Video/Music is set to "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"; MPOW-H10 is at the top of the device list there but clicking on it does nothing.  If I click on Test I actually hear a sound through the headphones, but Apply is greyed out.  How can I switch the output from the built-in audio (shown as selected) to the headphones?

If I knew why Apply is greyed out, I could probably get it working.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the missing step for me was to turn off all output sinks except for the Bluetooth headphones.  When I did that, my headphone sound took over from the laptop speakers.  But I still get some annoying background clicks. I don't know if that's fixable.